# Need list comprehension that updates its exclusions as the list is made

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to find a way to update the 'filters' of my list comprehension as the list is generated, as the numbers generated affect the filtering of the numbers afterward. I have no idea what I should do. I should also state that I am at a beginner level, so while I don't need copy and paste code, I will need a definitive method to source my learning.

*Edit for clarification*: Algorithmically, I need to generate two lists in an alternating fashion, but in between each addition each list receives a new permanent filter, which will exclude certain inputs of each list in the future. I'm not even sure how to create one 'filter' list being separate from the main output, let alone two, but any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: That is not how list comprehension works. The idea is that it is *declarative*, so fixed filters.

Comment: Use explicit recursion, or possibly `foldr` -- but explicit recursion look easier.

Comment: Or perhaps one can use a reference to the list being generated. For instance for prime numbers this works.

Comment: look at `span` and `break`, also at section 3.11 of the Haskell Report where list comprehensions are defined in terms of `if/then/else` and `concatMap`.

Comment: make your filter refer by name to the list being produced from the list comprehension, like [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Optimal_trial_division).

Comment: You've got plenty of good suggestions in the comments here, but you won't get any concrete answers unless you include what you've tried (i.e. code). As it stands, this is much too abstract to give a concrete answer.

Comment: Even more to the point, we need a clear, concrete problem statement accompanied by examples of arguments and desired results.